# Resolve double auction orders

Tags: beginner, clojure

Given a vector of seller orders (asks) of a certain product (each order having a price) and buyer orders (bids) of the same product, I'm creating a function that resolves the auction by matching the best sellers (lowest asked price) with the best buyers (higher offered price) and then clears the market by selecting a price and 'performing' the transactions between all suitable traders.

I'm experienced as programmer but I'm new to Clojure (or any Lisp), so this question is about the "Clojure way" of doing things so that the resulting code is readable, maintainable and efficient.

```clj
(ns trade-routes.core
  (:gen-class))


(defn as-trade-result 
  [ask bid]
  (let [bid-price (:price bid) ask-price (:price ask)]
    {:traded (<= ask-price bid-price) :bid bid :ask ask}
    )
)

(defn trade-price-tagger
  [price]
    (fn [trade] (merge trade {:price price}))
  )

(defn bid-price
  [trade]
  (-> trade :bid :price))

(defn average
  [a b]
  (* 0.5 (+ a b)))

(defn resolve-auction
  "Returns a list of trades and unresolved seller asks orders and buyer bids orders.
  The highest asks are matched with the lowest bids until all bids are greater than all asks"
  [asks bids]
  (let [best-asks (sort-by :price asks) 
        best-bids (reverse (sort-by :price bids))
        succesful-trades (first (partition-by 
            :traded 
            (map as-trade-result
                 best-asks 
                 best-bids)))
        breakeven-successful-trade (last succesful-trades)
        breakeven-price (average 
                          (bid-price breakeven-successful-trade) 
                          (bid-price breakeven-successful-trade))]
    (map (trade-price-tagger breakeven-price) succesful-trades)))

(defn random-order
    [min max]
    {:price (+ min (rand (- max min)))}
  )

(defn gen-random-orders
    "Create 'total' random orders with price between min and max"
    [total min max]
   (take total (repeatedly #(random-order min max)))
  )

(def test-asks (gen-random-orders 1000 20 100))
(def test-bids (gen-random-orders 1000 0 25))

(defn -main
  "Just tests with test-asks and test-bids."
  [& args]
  (let [succesful-trades (resolve-auction test-asks test-bids)]
   (println (str "There were " (count succesful-trades) " trades"))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formatting

It's common to see `let`-bindings vertically aligned, one per line. You've done that further down in `resolve-auction`, but even with just two name-value pairs it can be easier to see the logical parts vertically. The closing brackets (any kind) are also usually on the last line of the form, as opposed to indented back out. So

```
(defn as-trade-result 
  [ask bid]
  (let [bid-price (:price bid) ask-price (:price ask)]
    {:traded (<= ask-price bid-price) :bid bid :ask ask}
    )
)
```

would more idiomatically be formatted as

```
(defn as-trade-result
  [ask bid]
  (let [bid-price (:price bid)
        ask-price (:price ask)]
    {:traded (<= ask-price bid-price)
     :ask ask
     :bid bid}))
```

#### Semantic indentation

Also, the indentation here with `(first (partition-by` ending the line:

```
(let [best-asks (sort-by :price asks) 
      best-bids (reverse (sort-by :price bids))
      succesful-trades (first (partition-by 
          :traded 
          (map as-trade-result
               best-asks 
               best-bids)))
```

would more commonly be written in a way that reads left-to-right, top-to-bottom, in terms of expressions. Here are some examples:

```
(let [best-asks (sort-by :price asks)
      best-bids (sort-by (comp - :price) bids) ; negated :price gives you (reverse) in a single pass
      successful-trades
      (first
        (partition-by :traded (map as-trade-result best-asks best-bids)))]

      ; or

      successful-trades
      (->> (map as-trade-result best-asks best-bids)
           (partition-by :traded)
           first)
```

The point here is that the indentation is not just a continuation, but actually shows the code structure. Something in the (bottom) right is expected to flow towards the (top) left.

When you get used to this it makes reading code much faster because it's easy to see what is dependent on what, structure-wise.

Side note: since you only want the first group the `partition-by` is overkill. Consider [`take-while`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/take-while):

```
      successful-trades
      (->> (map as-trade-result best-asks best-bids)
           (take-while :traded))
```

---

### Expose more of the data

There is a balance here between encapsulating complex logic and making things clear. Someone familiar with Clojure knows instantly what `assoc`, `merge`, and so on mean. It's less clear exactly what a `trade-price-tagger` does until one looks it up. For relatively simple cases like that, using an inline function is idiomatic and arguably more clear. Compare:

```
(defn trade-price-tagger
  [price]
    (fn [trade] (merge trade {:price price}))
  )
...
(map (trade-price-tagger breakeven-price) succesful-trades)
```

with

```
(map #(assoc % :price breakeven-price) succesful-trades)
```

Similarly, accessors like

```
(defn bid-price
  [trade]
  (-> trade :bid :price))

(bid-price breakeven-successful-trade)
```

can be useful for deep objects or large programs, but in something short like this `(get-in)` could be fine:

```
(get-in breakeven-successful-trade [:bid :price])
```

---

In general I think this is readable and reasonably structured. Nice work as someone new to Clojure/Lisp!

My only other suggestion would be potentially to split up `resolve-auction`. The first half could be a function `(defn get-successful-trades [asks bids])`, and `resolve-auction` could just do the tagging of the breakeven point.

Comment: @Ezequiel You might be interested in the [Parinfer editor](https://github.com/shaunlebron/parinfer) in [Nightcode](https://sekao.net/nightcode/).

Answer (score 1):

I won't repeat [BenC's good advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140518/43360).

You want your code to be *readable, maintainable and efficient*. It should first be correct.

> [Make it work, make it right, make it fast](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast).

**Problems with `resolve-auction`**

*An apparent error*

```
(let [ ...
        breakeven-price (average 
                          (bid-price breakeven-successful-trade) 
                          (bid-price breakeven-successful-trade))]
```

... does not make sense. You forgot, I think, to define

```
(defn ask-price
  [trade]
  (-> trade :ask :price))
```

Then

```
(let [ ...
        breakeven-price (average 
                          (ask-price breakeven-successful-trade) 
                          (bid-price breakeven-successful-trade))]
```

Note:

This apparent error is not one in fact. The author's comment explains that the code is a long-winded way to achieve ...

```
(let [ ...
        breakeven-price (ask-price breakeven-successful-trade)]
```

*Misleading doc string*

The doc-string says that `resolve-auction` ...

> returns a list of trades and unresolved seller asks orders and buyer
>   bids orders

It doesn't. It just returns a list of trades.

*Superfluous data*

A *trade* consists of

- a *bid*
- an *ask*, and
- a *price*.

We don't need a *traded* flag: it is `true` by definition.

*The expression for `succesful-trades`*

The successful matches precede the unsuccessful ones. So `partition-by` is a poor choice for finding the successful trades, since it goes through all the failures too. A better choice  is `take-while`, which will stop when it runs out of successes.

If you are going to use `partition-by`, don't select the successful trades with `first`. That depends on the `:traded true` entry preceding the `:traded false` one, which it may not. And if there are no successes, you'll get the failures. Using `#(get % true)` instead of `first` will always get the successes. For example ...

```
(resolve-auction [{:price 5}] [{:price 3}])
;({:price 3.0, :traded false, :bid {:price 3}, :ask {:price 5}})
```

**A revised `resolve-auction`**

Taking the above into account, we end up with ...

```
(defn resolve-auction [asks bids]
  (let [asks (sort-by :price asks)
        bids (sort-by (comp - :price) bids)
        matches (map (fn [a b] {:ask a :bid b}) asks bids)
        trades (take-while #(<= (-> % :ask :price) (-> % :bid :price)) matches)
        trading-price (->> trades
                           last
                           vals
                           (map :price)
                           average)]
    (map #(assoc % :price trading-price) trades)))
```

Notes

- `bids` and `asks` are shadowed, to show that the
  function makes no further use of the supplied ones.
- Both `map` and `take-while` are lazy, so will explore only as far as
  the successful `matches`.
- The `trading-price` could be anything between the ask and the bid
  price of the last trade.

This calls only one local function, `average`, which we have to rewrite to accept a pair of numbers:

```
(defn average [[a b]]
  (* 0.5 (+ a b)))
```

**Test effectively**

Testing with random data is only effective if you can calculate what you expect and check it. Small specific examples find most errors.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Since I posted this question I made several modifications to this, the averaging of bid prices is an error because the average was not needed... but using only the bid price is a valid alternative to using the average between bid and ask (it depends on the rules of the auction). I improved my code a lot based on BenC's suggestions and also simplified my data a lot. I wish the process was more iterative and I could submit updates

Comment: @Ezequiel You make two good points. Versioning would turn each question into a kind of blog. You can suggest this on [Code Review Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/). I'll add a note to the answer to deal with pricing.

Comment: @Ezequiel You can submit updates to your question - click on [edit](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/140352/edit) beneath it. For example, you can add new versions of your code. It is bad practice to pull the rug from under existing answers.